# How to create an executable jar of a Lagom project

Tags: java, lagom

My project has one service (api and impl). How do I create an executable jar for my service. Since Lagom uses the service locator and service gateway for managing services, they need to be included in the jar as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an executable jar, use [`sbt-assembly`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly). Since Lagom is built on Play, the [Play sbt-assembly instructions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying#Using-the-SBT-assembly-plugin) may be useful here.

You can bundle whatever implementation of the service locator you like, if you only have one service though, then you don't need any service locator since that service isn't going to be looking up any other services, you can just provide a `ServiceLocator` implementation that returns `None` for every lookup. And as far as a service gateway goes, you can't bundle a service gateway inside a service since that defeats the purpose - a service gateway is an HTTP proxy that sits in front of and routes requests to many services. Typically you would use nginx or haproxy.

Comment: Thanks, my project is in Java and uses maven for build process. I can use the maven assembly plugin but what class should I use for the main class attribute in the plugin. The service (api and impl) does not have a main class.